# Prepare statement fails but no error was returned

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

For some strange reason the preparation of the query fails, I checked ten thousand times and parameters are correct as well as the table. Here is my code:

```
foreach($decoded as $caption)
{
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, leagueCode FROM league"))
{
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $leagueCode);
    $stmt->execute();
    var_dump($stmt);
    while($stmt->fetch())
    {
        if($leagueCode == $caption['league'])
        {
            if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO soccerseason (id, caption, league, years, numberOfTeams, numberOfGames, lastUpdated, self, teams, fixtures, leagueTable) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) 
            {
                $id_fk = $id;
                $caption = $caption['caption'];
                $league = $caption['league'];
                $years = $caption['year'];
                $not = $caption['numberOfTeams'];
                $nog = $caption['numberOfGames'];
                $lu = $caption['lastUpdated'];
                $self = $caption['_links']['self']['href'];
                $teams = $caption['_links']['teams']['href'];
                $fix = $caption['_links']['fixtures']['href'];
                $lt = $caption['_links']['leagueTable']['href'];

                if ($stmt->bind_param("isssiisssss", $id_fk, $caption, $league, $years, $not, $nog, $lu, $self, $teams, $fix, $lt)) 
                {
                    if ($stmt->execute()) 
                    {
                        echo "Done!";
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        die($mysqli->error);
                    }
                } 
                else 
                {
                    die($mysqli->error);
                }
            } 
            else 
            {

                die('execute() failed: ' . $mysqli->error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I tried to make a print in the else object but I get only the word

> execute() failed:

```
else 
{
    die('execute() failed: ' . $mysqli->error);
}
```

and it seems that `$mysqli->error` is null because it is not printed, why this happens? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `year` is a reserved word.

Comment: if the prepare fails, then you need to check for failure there. trying to execute a failed prepare is pointless.

Comment: I've changed the year with years in the table structure and in the code, same problen.

Comment: gotta love those `{...}` who knows if what's in there, is actually the right syntax and not missing anything? Not to mention which API used to connect with and if it's even executed

Comment: The variable and the syntax is correct see my update.

Comment: still unclear as to where `$caption` is being pulled in from. Replace `if ($stmt->execute())` with `if(!$statement->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$mysqli->error, E_USER_WARNING);}` and see what pops up.

Comment: The problem's that the code doesn't enter in the first condition but goes to the else of the first condition, so I can't see the pops up with your code.

Comment: I've printed the stmt connection var_dump($stmt); and is returned false, maybe this is the problem

Comment: well, your posted code contains one too many braces, the one at the very end `}`. If that's your full conditional statement, error reporting should be throwing you an unexpected end of file warning/notice. you should post more code for that `$stmt` and connection used for this.

Comment: Check the full code in the post

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem, and I realized that if you use the same connection for some reason the parameters of the object are lost, so you must use `$stmt-> store_result();` after the execution of the same.
I solved the problem, I hope my answer can be helpful.